# how to make VBA Class method return an object

Tags: vba, class

I wrote a Class representing a geometric Vector (defined by x and y coordinates) and I would like to make one of its method return an object of similar type by performing a simple translation

The Cass would be named Vxy and its code is:

```
Option Explicit
''+------------------------------------------------------------------+
''| Class Vector defined by x and y                                  |
''+------------------------------------------------------------------+
Private px As Double: Private py As Double
Public Property Get x() As Double:    x = px:            End Property
Public Property Let x(d As Double):  px = d:             End Property
Public Property Get y() As Double:    y = py:            End Property
Public Property Let y(d As Double):  py = d:             End Property
''+------------------------------------------------------------------+
''| Method Translation                                               |
''|                                                                  |
''+------------------------------------------------------------------+
Function Ts(V As Vxy) As Vxy 
 Set Ts = CreateObject("Vxy")
 Ts.x = Me.x + V.x
 Ts.y = Me.y + V.y
End Function
```

The code that tries to create objects of above class is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
''+------------------------------------------------------------------+
''| Testing Vectors                                                  |
''|                                                                  |
''+------------------------------------------------------------------+
Sub test_Vectors()
Dim V As New Vxy
 V.x = 3
 V.y = 4:
MsgBox V.a:
MsgBox V.l: ' Ok
Dim V_translated As New Vxy: V_translated = V.Ts(V) 'ERROR HERE
MsgBox V_translated.x: MsgBox V_translated.y:
End Sub
```

The error is: Run-time error 429: ActiveX component can't create object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateObject("Vxy")` will attempt to look up the CSLID of your object in the registry to instantiate a late-bound instance of it. It's running in VBA, so it will obviously never get registered.  Simply replace that with the early-bound version:

```
Set Ts = New Vxy
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant late bind to a local class with `CreateObject("Vxy")` (which raises your 429 error) instead:

```
Set Ts = new Vxy
```

You also need to `Set` object references so:

```
Set V_translated = V.Ts(V)
```